# Ascii Error when building Nikola on 10.7.5

Tags: python, macos, ascii, osx-lion, nikola

High, 
I'm new to the terminal language, therefor I'm totally lost since I've pushed a little too far my journey into it.

Here's the thing. I'm on mac 10.7.5, working on a site under Nikola, and trying to install Jekyll (... don't judge my naivety please), so I install and uninstall, upgrade and update a bunch of things I don't equally remember. 
Trying to install Python3, install GCC, updating a few bundles there, throwing away some TigerBrew or Macports here, sudopassing some troubles on brew doctor... In short, a happy mess in which I slowly drown, till :

julien:nikola julien$ nikola build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nikola", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nikola/**main**.py", line 136, in main
    LOGGER.error('"{0}" cannot be parsed.\n{1}'.format(conf_filename, msg))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)

Can you help me please ? Thanks a lotlotlot

Comment: You are using python2 instead of python3. Try aliasing by opening the terminal and type: alias python='python3'

Comment: It's telling me 
julien:~ julien$ alias python='python3' 
julien:~ julien$ python -version
-bash: python3: command not found

Comment: try: brew install python3